# UIImagePickerController has issue "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot....."

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, i have added 1 `UICollectionview` and use `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo and then upload to server, `collectionview` is used to display all photos. But when I click on Camera button in my app to open Camera, I received the warning `Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.` in console log. Sometime the camera screen is black screen. I tried searching but i cannot solve this issue. Can you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this happening on ios 8?  If so, I think it's not a duplicate

Comment: @RyanDignard: No, it happened on ios 7 & ios 8, but i cannot resolved this issue. Can you give me some solution?

Comment: @NTNT I'm encountering this error as well. Whenever it occurs, the image preview that pops up once a new picture has been taken is completely black. However, the "Re-Take" and "Use Photo" buttons at the bottom of the screen still appear and function properly. Are you witnessing this same behavior?